# Supermicro SYS-5019S-M and IPMI temperature threshold

Tags: ipmi, supermicro, alerting

I have a Supermicro SYS-5019S-M server configured to send an SMTP alert (an email) when IPMI detects that temperatures exceed some defined threshold.

However it seems that, for some component at least, the threshold is way to high: for example, both "System Temp" and "Peripheral Temp" critical limit are set at 85° C, which is way too much for, say, hard-disks.

[image]

So I have two questions:

- why the threshold are set so high? It is for some specific reason?
- how can I change them via the integrated Web IPMI interface and/or via Supermicro IPMIView (note: I know how to change them via ipmitools on Linux. I was just wondering if a specific Supermicro procedure/utility exists).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after some time I obtained a definitive answer from SuperMicro. Quoting it:

> System Temperature RT1 represents local inlet air temperature inside
>   the system and Peripheral Temperature RT2 provides a reference
>   temperature for system fan speed controls regarding add-on card area.
>   RT1 is also placed near the VRM's that will produce heat when the
>   system is on. **The critical temperature threshold of RT1 and RT2 at 85
>   C is referred to input and output capacitors’ temperature specs since
>   RT1 and RT2 both are PCB surface-mounted temperature sensors.** Under
>   normal operating conditions, the critical temperature threshold of RT1
>   and RT2 should not be reached.

So, "System Temp" (RT1) is the incoming (front) air temperature, while "Peripheral Temp" (RT2) is the outgoing (rear) air temperature.

However, it seems the critical temperature of both "System Temp" (RT1) and "Peripheral Temp" (RT2) are **not** the critical temperatures past which the system is at risk, rather are the **physical sensors own max tolerated temperature**

In short, the maximum/critical temperatures are set way too high to be useful for pre-emptive error reporting. You can lower them by using `ipmitool`; for example by issuing the following commands (this is a FreeNAS box, but Linux should be the same):

```
root@nas:~ # ipmitool sensor thresh "System Temp" upper 40 50 60
root@nas:~ # ipmitool sensor thresh "Peripheral Temp" upper 50 60 70
```